# Question about Dirichlet kernel of Fourier transform for $f\in L^p$ with $p\in [1,2]$, help needed in understanding proof.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, dirichlet-convolution

I am trying to understand the proof that the following two statements are equivalent. For fixed $R>0$ and $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ let 
$$S_Rf(x)=\int_{|\xi|<R} \hat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi i x . \xi}\,d\xi.$$

1) For all $f\in L^p$, $S_Rf \to f$ in $L^p$ as $R\to \infty$.

2) There exists a constant $c>0$ depending only on $p$ such that $||S_Rf||_{L^p}\leq c||f||_{L^p}$ for all $f$

Basically I have read everywhere that for 1) $\implies$ 2) (this is the direction I am interested in) you use the UBP but this is what I'm having difficulty understanding! How, for fixed $R>0$, is $S_R : L^p \to L^p$ a bounded map? I don't even see how $S_Rf$ is even in $L^p$? Any help would be appreciated, I've been trying to work it out for hours now. Thanks

Comment: This may be a silly question, but does anything prevent you from using the ML lemma to get an upper bound in terms of the length of the contour and $\hat{f}$, and then the apply ML lemma again on $\hat{f}$?

Comment: @JessicaK You mean to bound $|S_Rf(x)|$ for fixed x? Yes this can be done but I'm looking for a bound on $||S_Rf||_{L^p}$. It would probably work if you could do something with $||\hat{f}||_{L^{\infty}}$

Comment: @JessicaK What contour??? You're totally misreading something...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I don't want to detract from OPs question any further. My original comment wasn't supposed to be a hint. I just assumed that it was natural to treat the integral to be the area measure on $\{\lvert \xi \rvert < R\}$ and use polar coordinates to change it into a double integral where the $``d\theta"$ part would be the contour. I'm pretty new to math still, sorry for intruding!

Comment: Could be interesting, of course if would be n-dimensional spherical coordinates not 2-d polar. That seems like a lot of work though.

Comment: Tje theorem of Feffermann stated here (https://lewko.wordpress.com/2009/08/04/feffermans-ball-multiplier-counterexample/) shows that your doubt is very well founded. It is not true that $S_R $ is a bounded linear map (for $n>1$ and $p\neq 2$).